# How to automatically adjust width of active pane in ConEmu Terminal

Tags: conemu

I'd like to configure ConEmu in the following manner:
If I have several existing open consoles in a split window, the active console automatically takes xx% of the width and the other splits take a smaller portion.

In the picture below the left console is active (I am currently working there) and it is wide. When I switch to the right console (the one that is inactive in the picture), I would like this right console to become wider and the left one narrow. This should happen automatically.

[image]

I found the documentation for the [Gui Macros](https://conemu.github.io/en/GuiMacro.html#Split) that allow me to

> [...m]ove splitter between panes (aka resize panes)

However I am stuck with implementing the feature above.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: What do you want in fact: resize your current splits or start panes in desired configuration?

Comment: @Maximus, thanks for looking at this. I would like to resize current panes (splits) that are already open.

Comment: Your question is too abstract. GuiMacro is intended to execute some actions. No problem, but you didn't tell us what actions you want to execute. What have you tried and what is the problem?

Comment: @Maximus, thanks again for your comment. I added a screenshot.